# aligning my images so they sit next to each other

Tags: html, css

I'm echoing out a few images which all works fine but my problem is they are all going down the page example

image 1

image 2

image 3

and I'd like to make them so they sit next to each other like so

image 1  image 2  image 3

and so on. I have tried to add inline into the CSS for my `div` tag but it does not work...

```
                                <div class="auction_box" style="height:150px">

                                <form name="myform" action="userbox.php" method="POST">
                                <p> </p>
                                <p> </p>
                                <p> </p>






    <p align="center"><a href="smalldex.php?name='.$battle_get['name'].'"?KeepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=400&amp;width=600" class="thickbox"><img src="http://pokemontoxic.net/img/pokemon/'.$v->type.''.$battle_get['pic'].'" width="" height="" border="0" /></a></p>
      <p align="center"><span style="height: 70px; text-align: center;">





                                    Name:<br/>' .$v->pokemon. '<br/>
                                    Level:' .$v->level. '<br/>
                                    Exp:' .$v->exp. '<br/>
                                    Gender:' .$v->gender. '<br/>
                                    Type:' .$v->type. '<br/>

    Slot you want to put your pokemon in


<select name="mydropdown">

<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>


<input type="hidden" name="myName" value="'.$v->id.'" />
                                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"> 



                                </form>
                                </div>';
```

You can see that the `div` is called `auction_box`.  I have tried a lot of things in CSS but has not worked...  I'd like them all next to each other.

Has you can see the image is this part

```
   <p align="center"><a href="smalldex.php?name='.$battle_get['name'].'"?KeepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=400&amp;width=600" class="thickbox"><img src="http://pokemontoxic.net/img/pokemon/'.$v->type.''.$battle_get['pic'].'" width="" height="" border="0" /></a></p>
      <p align="center"><span style="height: 70px; text-align: center;">
```

I'd like the whole echo ( e.g the levels has well has the pic ) to be inline.

Comment: you can use table to align them instead of using css

Comment: @sohaan, that's a terrible suggestion.  `table`'s are for tabulating data, `div`'s are for layout.

Comment: google does not like tables :) how would i do that anyways ? Into rows

Comment: You have not posted code with 3 images in it. `display:inline` would be a correct way to achieve what you want.

Comment: OP, you also need to post the _relevant_ code.  Where is the CSS?  Where is the HTML for the three images?

Comment: Are you setting the width for your three `div`'s anyplace?  A `div` will take the full width of its parent unless you specify.

Comment: nope im not telling the div the width.

Comment: Then that's your whole problem... no amount of `inline` CSS will fix that.

Comment: Give each one a width!... in conjunction with `inline` OR in conjunction with vikrantx's `float` answer below.

Comment: Just gave it width but still not inline.... there all up and down the page LOL

Comment: hey @Sparky672 i know tables are for tabulating data anyways how about  using unordered list and and putting <li> inline

Comment: To the OP:  Create a jsFiddle demo that shows your broken code.  Clearly, [this is working](http://jsfiddle.net/4d6Hc/).

Comment: it works in the link u showed but not on my website... seen has i have a echo .... and a lot of code... maybe post the div tags with the shown code in ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use style **float:left** to container where that images are placed like

```
<div style="width:500 px">
<div style="float:left; width:100 px">Image 1</div>
<div style="float:left; width:100 px">Image 2</div>
<div style="float:left; width:100 px">Image 3</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work.    It puts them next to each other but not inline so one is at the top of the page and the next is half way down but next to it

Comment: To both of you... this only works when you set the width of all three so they fit side-by-side within the parent.

Answer (score 3):

Make `width`'s whatever you want as long as the children fit within the parent.  (`border`'s & `padding` will count against `width`.)

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4d6Hc/)

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="image">Image 1</div>
    <div class="image">Image 2</div>
    <div class="image">Image 3</div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    width: 900px;
}

.image {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This just moves them to the left but still down the page