# Breakdown basic CSS for magento

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a 3 row column with left flow .

But the images does not manage to stack evenly.

http://postimg.org/gallery/2rvz3g8aa/4883b968/

1. Can you see what's wrong with the code or what I can improve?

https://jsfiddle.net/68fwd88c/

```
    <div class="mar-btm">
<div class="con-top">
<div class="top-one" style="float: left;"><a href="{{store url=""}}massanzug" target="_self"><img onmouseover="this.src='{{media url="wysiwyg/Landingpage_1200pix_03_1.jpg"}}';" onmouseout="this.src='{{media url="wysiwyg/Landingpage_1200pixohne_03.jpg"}}';" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Landingpage_1200pix_03_1.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="top-two" style="float: left;"><a href="{{store url=""}}masshemden" target="_self"><img onmouseover="this.src='{{media url="wysiwyg/imroivedpix_05.jpg"}}';" onmouseout="this.src='{{media url="wysiwyg/imprved_05.jpg"}}';" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/imprved_05.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="top-three" style="float: right;"><img onmouseover="this.src='{{media url="wysiwyg/Landingpage_1200pix_08.jpg"}}';" onmouseout="this.src='{{media url="wysiwyg/OHNE.TEXT_Landingpage_1200pix_08.jpg"}}';" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/OHNE.TEXT_Landingpage_1200pix_08.jpg"}}" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

2. PS. I build on top of an old employees code. What does "mar-btm" refer to? (i assume it is margin bottom) what is "con-top" could not find "con" on w3schools_com/css

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4d6Hc/ Got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969159/aligning-my-images-so-they-sit-next-to-each-other

Comment: ok, i made an update. Is this better?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/68fwd88c/ or as a code block..

Comment: I got 3 rows with this code from answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969159/aligning-my-images-so-they-sit-next-to-each-other

Comment: Though i wonder why our former employee use the before mentioned code, and what the individual parts mean? "can-top" "mar-btm"

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, do you not see the code? I see this: https://jsfiddle.net/68fwd88c/ or as a code block.. Can't you see it? I see the code on my screen? [url=http://postimg.org/image/x5i0i0e8z/][img]http://s13.postimg.org/x5i0i0e8z/Screen_Shot_2015_06_08_at_13_07_49.jpg[/img][/url]

Comment: @Mastervision it wasn't in the question at the time of my comment. Now I can see it.

Comment: How do i do the same with text boxes? Assuming you would put text boxes underneath?

Comment: To be honest, it is going to be very hard for the rest of us to figure out what is going on unless you give us a jsfiddle or something else that actually produces output.  What you have there has too much missing (the class names probably invoke some css that you haven't provided, and the {{=}} code probably is processed by something or another to provide real values).  Mitch showed you what kind of jsfiddle we need.  At a guess, though, your problem is that your images are not of the same size.  Please fix the code or delete the question.  Thanks.